# Windows Encryption Software that is for files, not drives?

Tags: encryption

With TrueCrypt I can create an entire volume and put files into there. However with regards to syncing on other devices or the cloud, this become problematic because if one file changes bam, everything has to be uploaded. Also many services do not handle gigabyte sized files at well, or at all. Is there a software that can

1. Encrypts my files individually, not volumes.
2. Allows me to access these files un-hindered on my device, once I have unlocked the device with a key or passcode. For example with truecrypt, once it is mounted I have complete/direct access to my files
3. Allows me to access the files just as un-hindered on other devices the same one (it isn't baked into the OS or anything only).
4. Similar to number 1., the files are actually encrypted wherever they are stored, be it on a device or in the cloud.
5. The private keys which are generated are mine, they are not generated by an application which could potentially connect to the internet and "leak" them. I think there are some dropbox-esq applications out there for encryption but I do not feel secure with their guarantees.

Comment: Voting to close without any comment? This site really lacks proper moderation etiquette, yet forces all of the users into ornate rules.

Comment: Whats wrong with a TrueCrypt container?  We really are not the place to request a list possible solutions.  Your requirements are pretty specific.

Comment: First sentance covers the con of TC volumes. And this this question isn't too specific. How is a secure solution specific? With all of the PRISM stuff going on (very relevant) we can see first hand that conglomerate "privacy" software is potentially rigged and unsecured. The idea that the application which generates your private keys is network connected to a central server is not secure. As for the second point, yes Ramhound... any question which involves enumerating software is often voted to closed here. Usually without considering the actual content of the question.

Comment: When you used the word "volume" I assumed you mean encrypting an entire parition not using a Truecrypt container which is a single file to the host operating system.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has had this feature built in since Windows XP.  Its called Encrypted File System ([EFS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmar/archive/2012/01/30/what-is-encrypting-file-system-efs-in-windows-7.aspx)).  You can encrypt files and/or folders.  You should read up on it, to see exactly how it works, but here are some quick directions on how to enable it for a file or folder:

- Right click a file
- Select `Properties`
- On the `General Tab` click the `Advanced` button
- Check the `Encypt contents to secure data` checkbox

Again, you should read up on how it works, especially when encrypting folders.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [PGP/GPG](http://gnupg.org/).
there are clients for most platforms, you can cipher individual files, and you can generate your own keys or import them if you already have a keyring, and export them for use on other devices as needed.

Answer (score 0):

"[AxCrypt](http://www.axantum.com/axcrypt/) is the leading open source file encryption software for Windows. It integrates seamlessly with Windows to compress, encrypt, decrypt, store, send and work with individual files."

Comment: No no no to AxCrypt. It will install adware into Chrome which uses CSS to annoy the hell out of you with popups.

Comment: Not many free software's don't force you to opt out of something...the install allows "You may decline OpenCandy offers by selecting the 'I do not accept' radio buttton at the offer screen, and Softonic offers by unchecking the checkbox.", the interweb is a dangerous domain!

Comment: @Zombies - If you have problem with the community then leave.  there is nothing wrong with this answer.

Comment: As I said earlier, I want to un-do my downvote but "crapexchange" won't let me. However the mods deleted that so the context has been lost.